# Why can't antiseptics and other chemicals be used against fungal Infections?

Tags: home-remedies, fungal-infection

Fungal infections in humans are generally cutaneous [and not lethal](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3420938/)

> Mammals are highly resistant to systemic fungal diseases. Whereas dermatophyte-associated diseases are common, these are seldom life threatening

It is recommended to visit the doctor and apply anti-fungal lotions for treatment of cutaneous fungal infection and to refrain from home remedies. [Say this.](https://www.healthline.com/health/ringworm#symptoms)

However sometimes a person may be too busy to get to the doctor in time. Say a student studying for an exam or one with a busy work schedule.

I have read of a few chemicals that can kill fungi:

1. [Antiseptics and Disinfectants](https://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/difference-between-disinfectants-antiseptics)

   > They kill microorganisms such as bacteria, viruses, and fungi using chemicals called biocides.

   Disinfectants are harmful and should not be used on skin. But
   speaking from experience, a few drops of phenol,hospital
   disinfectant (and perhaps even HCl containing toilet cleaners)
   accidentally falling on the skin don't cause noticeable harm to the
   skin(outer layer's dead anyways)
2. Detergents: In school we had to [extract DNA from plant cells](https://www.biotech.iastate.edu/publications/lab_protocols/DNA_Extraction_Onion.html#:%7E:text=The%20detergent%20dissolves%20the%20fatty,the%20solution%2C%20leaving%20the%20DNA.) and the role of detergent was to destroy cell membranes. A small, localised amount of it won't harm.I have washed clothes and dishes with bare hands and there is no damage unless used for a long time.
3. Alcohol: Yeast poison themselves in wine making. This is the best candidate since sanitizers (and maybe homeopathic medicines, beverages) don't cause any harm to our skin but they certainly kill these organisms.

**So as long as the infection is not in a *sensitive/private* region, why can't we use small quatities of these chemicals (soaked
in a cloth, maybe) instead of costlier medications?** Less
quantities of these would kill more and kill much faster unlike
antifungal lotions(require atleast a week).  Besides they have [this
problem](https://www.cdc.gov/fungal/antifungal-resistance.html#:%7E:text=Fungi%20can%20develop%20resistance%20to,drugs%20designed%20to%20kill%20them.)

> Fungi can develop resistance to antifungal drugs the same way bacteria can develop resistance to antibiotics. Resistance happens when germs develop the ability to defeat the drugs designed to kill them.

In this case would personally prefer to reserve antifungal drugs etc. for if I get a much more serious inside the body infection.

Comment: Sorry for the length of the question. But I could find no other way of summarising everything while also providing enough references and showing research work

Comment: Also the links are optional to read. Not integral to the question but certainly informative and displaying research effort

Comment: Not all fungi are yeasts. There are antifungal treatments available in pharmacies (in the UK, at least). They tend to be ketoconazole or clotrimazole based topical meds (or related pharmaceuticals) - each specific to the fungus/area of the body involved. [Wikipedia on topical anti-fungals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topical_antifungal). Bear in mind that we don't address personal medical questions - those should be directed to your local medical professional. (They may indicate a more serious underlying condition)

Comment: WRT your statement about alcohol: you need to consider the degree of penetration topical alcohol has vs. topical medication formulated for skin infections. Alcohol is a potent disinfectant until it dissipates, which happens in seconds, so it's unlikely to penetrate to any degree. It's also a good solvent, so sticking your toe in ethanol and leaving it there might help, but, again, evaporation occurs quickly, and ethanol is a potent toxin to *all* cells, including skin. You'd kill the fungus at the cost of your skin.

Comment: That's not to say there are no safer alternatives, but do you want to slather your toe, say, with copious amounts of live-culture yogurt for days (and nights)?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. I know that all fungi are not yeasts but the three chemicals I mentioned should kill anything that is not already dead. And I am not looking for personal medical advice. Just why people require the doc or that much treatment for something so superficial(& simple). After all we don't go for every cold or take tetanus against every cut do we? (We wait to see if they show symptoms of seriousness or deterioration later on)

Comment: @anongoodnurse What about the more potent ones, I mentioned in the post ? Like  toilet cleaner or hospital floor disinfectant, detergent or even the antiseptic applied on wounds? The former 3 seem to be fast enough to kill fungi without killing skin (can be washed after) while the latter is applied on wounds(sometimes even open) so ..........?

Comment: You know this is a medical sciences site, well we answer questions about diseases, and treatments and a number of related biological processes - but, our questions should relate to recognized medical treatments, recognized diseases and what people refer to mainstream biological sciences as they relate to these. Home remedies relating to the use of toilet cleaner are obviously not on topic here. Sodium hydroxide dissolves skin rather dramatically, converting lipids to soap, as I'm sure you're aware. It's not recommended or recognised as a skin treatment for *any* condition.

Comment: If you've personal hypotheses that you feel need to be taken seriously, then you'd need to find a suitable place to post about them - off network, they're off-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Do you remember the furor that was caused by Trump when he suggested intravenous bleach to kill coronavirus? No physician, and I mean **not one**, uses disinfects/antiseptics medicinally as you describe for very good reasons. SE discourages discussions, and I don't like to answer a bunch of questions in comments, so let's leave it there.

Comment: This question leaves me trying to imagine someone using things like toilet cleaners on jock itch. You can use anything you want on yourself, but no doctor is ever going to use products that destroy skin unless destroying skin is the objective. There's that pesky "First, do no harm" thing.

Comment: @CareyGregory, human skin is a pretty good barrier against all sorts of things; a quick dip in various nasty chemicals won't cause problems.  (I know from personal experience that if you get concentrated hydrochloric acid on your skin, you've got about 20 seconds to rinse it off before it starts damaging the important bits.)

Comment: @Mark Good luck defending that logic against a good malpractice attorney when most skin fungal infections can be easily cured with safe OTC medications.